# My div doesn't stay inside my div container

Tags: css, html, containers

I have a three divs and I am giving them absolute positioning.  However, they are not staying inside my container div.

Here is the code:

```
<body >
    <div id="container">
        <div id="col1"> testing one</div>
        <div id="col2"> testing two</div>
        <div id="col3"> testing three</div>
        <br/><p/>ksjdlfkjsldkjfl;s
```

Here is the CSS for my three divs and my container:

```
div#container {
    position:reletive;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    margin: 100px 80px auto;
    padding: 0  100px10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    width: 800px;
     -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

div#col1{
    position:absolute;
    float: left;
    left:0;
    width:220px;
    background-color :red;
}

div#col2{
    position:absolute;
    float: left;
    left:220px;
    width:220px;
    background-color :yellow;
    padding: 10px auto ;
}

div#col3{
    position:absolute;
    float: left;
    left:500px;
    width:100px;
    background-color :green;
    padding: 10px auto;
}
```

Comment: div#container.position has a spelling error.
 position:reletive; to  position:relative;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, firstly, the position of container div should be "relative" , not the "reletive".
Secondly, I think you should use "relative" position instead of "absolute".

Comment: what is the difference between absolute and relative?